# How do I use/install VIZ in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/viz/launching_viz/launching_viz.html#launching-viz).  When I run the code I get

```
"g++ -std=c++11 d.cpp -o d `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
d.cpp:20:27: fatal error: opencv2/viz.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/viz.hpp>
                           ^
compilation terminated.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Fri May  9 01:22:57
"
```

Whats going on? How do I use/install viz? The viz folder is in the `<OpenCV-Source-Directory>/modules` folder and `viz.hpp` is there, I build the Itseez version of OpenCV.

Could use a little advice, the tutotials/google say nothing.

Comment: btw, your link above points to the master(3.0) version, [the 2.4.9 version is here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/viz/launching_viz/launching_viz.html#launching-viz)

Comment: asking on [opencv's own qa site](http://answers.opencv.org/) might yield a chance to reach the author of that module even. (bear with them, it's pretty new, like 2 weeks in the official 2.4 branch only)

Comment: @berak thanks man, I like saying on top of the game and getting the latest greatest by using the 3.0 version

Answer (score 4):

To use the viz module in opencv you need:

1) Build, compile and install VTK library.
Download the last VTK version:
      http://www.vtk.org/download/
Go to VTK folder:

```
cd /Users/myUser/Documents/VTK
```

Create build folder:

```
mkdir build

cd build
```

Set the cmake parameters to use viz module with opencv. To do this We will write in console:

```
ccmake .
```

And it's going to show a configuration window from cmake (I can't put the image). Then you need to cross the window with down keyboard and try to find the next parameters to change it. Finally the parameters should be like this:

```
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS = ON

BUILD_TESTING = ON

CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Release

CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = /Users/myUser/Documents/VTK/build

QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE = /usr/local/bin/qmake
```

Then push 't' and in this window:

Cross the file with down-keyboard (now you need to keep the key much more time) to find the nexts parameters and to change it:

```
CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES: i386;x86_64

CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
```

Push 'c' to save the configuration and exit.
Now we can compile an install the VTK library:

```
cmake .

make

sudo make install
```

2) Build, compile and install opencv again, but when we are going we need to use WITH_VTK=ON (like morynicz says).
->Go to the opencv folder

```
cd /User/myUser/Documents/Opencv

mkdir build

cd build

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON –D WITH_VTK=ON ../

make

sudo make install
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [How to build 'opencv_viz' module](http://answers.opencv.org/question/32502/opencv-249-viz-module-not-there/?answer=32847#post-id-32847).

Comment: this looks like a "princess in another castle" answer to me https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Answer (score 1):

To build Viz you need to have VTK library installed and detected by cmake and then compile the OpenCV library with `WITH_VTK=ON` option.