# Why can't CMake find VTK_DIR when I try installing the VTK libraries for OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, build, vtk

This is directly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559925/how-do-i-use-install-viz-in-opencv) about installing OpenCV with VTK (I am using Windows 8.1, OpenCV 2.4.10, and VTK 6.3.0).

When I try to use CMake to re-build OpenCV with VTK it gives me an error regarding VTK_DIR. The VTK_DIR field has *VTK_DIR-NOTFOUND* as an entry and the configuration results state:

*VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file*

My VTK build folder contains a VTKConfig.cmake file, and I also found the same file in the \CMakeFiles folder, although the contents are different. If I switch VTK_DIR to the \CMakeFiles folder then I get a pop-up window with the message:

*Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid*

Based on what I have read, the most I should have to do is manually set VTK_DIR to be the build directory, and I assume that error is because I shouldn't be trying to use the file in \CMakeFiles. But manually setting the directory does not work (and I am positive the directory contains VTKConfig.cmake)

Here is the possible source of the problem: I am using Code::Blocks with the MinGW build of OpenCV (works without VTK), VTK needs to be built using Visual Studio (I generated using VS 2013 Win64 in CMake -- then built using VS 2013 Community edition), and then I am trying to re-build OpenCV with VTK generating for MinGW in CMake.

Regarding my VTK installation, should I be building the Debug or Release configuration of VTK? Both? Also, some tutorials indicate you [need to install VTK after building](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building/Windows) but [others don't](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgvbhyDh8r0). I build the ALL_BUILD project as directed but when I try Project Only->Build Project for the INSTALL project I get some errors -- they aren't listed the same as shown in screenshots (INSTALL is along with ZERO_CHECK in a folder called CMakePredefinedTargets). Instead I right-click on that folder and it successfully builds those two projects.

Comment: did you figure out?